# How can I access a 'collaboration id' log to troubleshoot a facebook login?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Can I access the B2C error logs with the standard B2C User flows (NOT a custom policy)?

My root problem is that using a default Azure AD B2C User flow, the facebook login doesn't work. To troubleshoot it I need to see the error from B2C.

The final error is 
https://*my-web-client-url*.azurewebsites.net/#error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C%3a+An+exception+has+occurred.%0d%0a**Correlation+ID%3a+1b85d65d-3697-4212-ad7d-ea5fb361783d%0d%0a**Timestamp%3a+2019-02-05+16%3a02%3a51Z%0d%0a

But the documentation for seeing the Correlation ID logs is for custom policies, not a default User Flow.

Details:

- The only MS documentation on accessing the logs is for custom policies (here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-troubleshoot-custom  ). However, I'm not using a custom user flow.
- prior to the error I see eight B2C<-->Facebook request/response pairs that return 302, so everything seems to be working up to that point.
- Using the Dashboard, the Azure AD B2C audit logs simply says 'B2C received a bad request'. Not very helpful.
- My facebook app settings has 'Valid OAuth Redirect URIs' set to "https://*my-tenant*.b2clogin.com/*my-tenant*.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp  , as per the AAD B2C documentation.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: I went ahead and created a custom policy, using facebook, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom
AND I set up Application Insights per the link in my question.
AFTER doing all of that and drilling down the root error is 
Message
An exception was caught when making a request to URL "https://graph.facebook.com/me" using method "GET". The exception status code was "BadRequest" with the following message: {scrubbed}.
"Scrubbed". Apparently Azure scrubs the error messages from facebook.

Answer (score 0):

As my comment above says, I had to use custom policies to see the logs, and even then the message was "scrubbed".

Turns out the *real* answer was to change my authentication tenant from my-tenant.**b2clogin**.com to my-tenant.**auth0**.com.

I ditched Azure AD B2C entirely, went to Auth0.com. It's working very well and profile pictures are part of the defaults.